# WTForms equivalent to <input type="datetime-local">

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to know if it's possible to create a dropdown datetime field for the DateTimeField in WTForms, the way  renders in HTML.
A dropdown menu is much more user friendly than the default in WTForms where a user has to type in the date and time in the exact correct format.
And if it's not possible using only WTForms then how would I be able to implement the raw HTML into a WTForm as I would still like to use the security CSRF token that is provided by WTForms.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The html5 fields provided by WTForms do include a DateTimeLocalField - [v2.3.x](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.html5.DateTimeLocalField), [v3.0.x](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.DateTimeLocalField). Thus (v2.3)

```
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DateTimeLocalField
dttm = DateTimeLocalField("Date/Time: ", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
```

will show the html5 date picker and time picker popups on browsers that support them (support is varied).

I find you need to specify `format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"` - note the T - because the default `format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"` fails validation (see quote below).

`input type="datetime"` appears to be deprecated, so browsers fall back to plain text entry: [input type="datetime" | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime).
`input type="datetime-local"`, and thus WTForms `DateTimeLocalField`, should always be used: [input type="datetime-local" | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local).

From the latter:

> One thing to note is that the displayed date and time formats differ from the actual value; the displayed date and time are formatted according to the user's locale as reported by their operating system, whereas the date/time value is always formatted YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm.

Answer (score 2):

Ok after being forced to read the WTForms documentation because nobody immediately answered my question I now understand that it can be manipulated to do anything HTML can do by passing in HTML keyword arguments like so:

{{ form.when.label }}<br>
{{ form.when(type='datetime-local') }}

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with us and answering your own question! (I don't know enough about WTForms to upvote, unfortunately, otherwise, I would.)

Comment: I'm sure I've read all the WTForms documentation but I didn't spot this - definitely upvoting!

Comment: Although, reading the WTForms documentation again ... what about DateTimeLocalField itself? :)

Comment: DateTimeLocalField that is the answer to my original question thank you :) Next time I will try to finish reading the docs instead of running with the first hacked solution I find.

Comment: Added it as an answer